# Rails 5 - Why we will get DOMException error in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, exception

In rails 5, I am using `"react": "^15.4.1"` for front-end.

I am getting an error like

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.
at removeChild (http://localhost:8080/js/main.js:20902:14)
at Object.processUpdates (http://localhost:8080/js/main.js:21046:11)
at Object.dangerouslyProcessChildrenUpdates [as processChildrenUpdates] (http://localhost:8080/js/main.js:82797:27)
at processQueue (http://localhost:8080/js/main.js:85253:29)
at ReactDOMComponent._updateChildren (http://localhost:8080/js/main.js:85471:9)
at ReactDOMComponent.updateChildren (http://localhost:8080/js/main.js:85415:12)
at ReactDOMComponent._updateDOMChildren (http://localhost:8080/js/main.js:82569:12)
at ReactDOMComponent.updateComponent (http://localhost:8080/js/main.js:82387:10)
at ReactDOMComponent.receiveComponent (http://localhost:8080/js/main.js:82349:10)
at Object.receiveComponent (http://localhost:8080/js/main.js:10257:22)
```

And also I am getting an another error like

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined
at Function._onError (main.js:362)
at main.js:304
at <anonymous>
```

Why these errors will come? Please help me to solve this issue, I am new to ReactJS.

Comment: the error is mainly the second snippet rest is just common when errors occur in react

Comment: Please show the code where that undefined error is thrown

Comment: whatever object you tried to use for getting status property is undefined